# Set number of options shown in a <select multiple> element to less than 4

Tags: html, internet-explorer, safari

```
< select size="2" multiple>
    < option value="1">1< /option>
    < option value="2">2< /option>
    < option value="3">3< /option>
    < option value="4">4< /option>
    < option value="5">5< /option>
    < option value="6">6< /option>
    < option value="7">7< /option>
    < option value="8">8< /option>
    < option value="9">9< /option>
    < option value="10">10< /option>
    < option value="11">11< /option>
    < option value="12">12< /option>
    < option value="13">13< /option>
< /select>
```

size attribute of Select tag is not working properly in Safari.

if size attribute's value is greater than four then there have no problem, its working.
But when I set the value of size less than four then it show four values.

above example displays four options in safari but I want two options.
What is the reason for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the reason is, but you can style the element using `height`.  Unfortunately, this makes it awkward to get it to look the same in each browser, although the example below looks close enough:

http://jsfiddle.net/D7ugW/

Comment: @Karandeep Singh: Which version of IE? It works for me in 8.  You could use a combination of `size=2` and `height: 36px` (or so), which would work in the version of IE it's not working for you in.

Comment: It seems that Safari has a built-in restriction on the `size` attribute value. To set the height using CSS, you can use the `em` unit, e.g. `2.7em` for two options, instead of needing to use pixel values that would not adapt to font size changes.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
height: calc(2em + 30px);
```