# How to set size-Attribute on select-element to 2 or 3 in webkit browsers?

Tags: html, webkit

This won't work:

```
<select size="2">
    <option>Mars</option>
    <option>Earth</option>
    <option>Jupiter</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uteb6/

It's not possible to set the size-attribute of select to 2 or 3. Any other value will work fine. Is there a solution? And why isn't this possible?

Jquerys `$('select').attr('size', '2');` won't work either.

Tested with Safari 5.1.7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set number of options shown in a <select multiple> element to less than 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014143/set-number-of-options-shown-in-a-select-multiple-element-to-less-than-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like that behavior isn't necessarily part of the specifications, at least in sitepoint:

> If the size is set to "1", or omitted entirely, the select will render as a pull-down list. If the value is greater than "1", the select renders as list of options. If the value of the size attribute is lower than the number of option elements contained in the select list, the browser will display a scroll bar control to indicate that there are more options to view or action below

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/select/size

You can use `height` css to adjust it though as you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/uteb6/10/

Comment: "If the value of the size attribute is lower than the number of option elements contained in the select list, the browser will display a scroll bar control to indicate that there are more options to view or action below" - This would indicate the above issue should not be an issue, and is not entirely true for OP.. That is very odd! I guess I don't have a complete answer.

Comment: Going the `height` route, it might be better to use `em` instead of `px` for compatibility and adaptable reasons.

Answer (score 0):

How about style?

```
<select size="2" style="height:40px">
```